# View positioning issue

Tags: ios, view

My ViewController's View has several subviews. On the user's action I add more subviews to it, and try to modify the positions of all the subviews. Only the positions of the newly added subviews are changing, the old ones are not.

If I change the positions of the old subviews without adding the new ones to my View, everything works as expected.

I've also tried changing their sizes. That appears to be working. The problem is only with the position.

Anyone encountered a similar problem? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I`ve tried by changing the center and by changing the origin of their frames.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     for (UIView *view in self.oldSubviews) {
                         view.center = center1;
                     }
                     for (UIView *view in self.newSubviews) {
                         view.center = center2;
                     }
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }];
```

When the views in the `newSubviews` aren't added as subviews, everything is fine. I've printed the array of `self.view.subviews` and there is no visible difference between the new and the old subviews.

This is what I tried with the frame:

```
for (UIView *view in self.oldSubviews) {
     CGRect frame = view.frame;
     frame.origin = CGPointZero;
     frame.size = CGSizeMake(150, 300);
     view.frame = frame;
}
```

Their sizes are changed, but they are not moved to the upper left corner.

Comment: are you changing the center property of your view when you are mentioning you are changing your view positions?

Comment: How are you saving references to these subviews? Are you referring to all of them when changing the frame? Code please...

Comment: Ok, found the issue, i guess. I was doing some settings in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method. I did not know, it is called after you add some subviews. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the issue, i guess. I was doing some settings in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method. I did not know, it is called after you add some subviews. Thanks for the help